# Inning with exits

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> Ice pie with mile.
>   It'll eye something big.
>   Inning with exits.
>   Met a land, would use.
>   Try kit with a Mal.
>   It & it makes a sound.

Answer is one word.

Comment: We already know "answer" is one word, but what do you want us to find? :P

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's a

> homonym

for

> I spy with my little eye 
>  Something beginning with X.
>  It's metal and wood.
>  You strike it with a mallet
>  And it makes a sound.

So it is

> XYLOPHONE

Comment: very nice! I love puzzles like these that are so satisfyingly simple, yet still absolutely stump me.

Comment: "ice pie" was the Aha!

Answer (score 2):

Its a:

> xylophone

Because

> the riddle is a homonym for the popular I spy game

Specifically:

> I spy with my little Eye something beginning with 'X'. Its metal and would, you strike it with a mallet and it makes a sound.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! It looks like someone beat you to this answer. Make sure in the future to check if your answer has already been said before you add it.